# Vertically Align Text to Image C#

Tags: c#, html, css, vertical-alignment

I am trying to vertically align text to the middle of an image. My code is as follows:

C#:

```
myBuilder.Append("class='img-valign'<img src='../myImages/checkmark.png' /> Successful Upload!").AppendLine();
```

CSS:

```
.img-valign {
vertical-align: middle;
margin-bottom: 0.75em;
```

It is currently not working,my guess is it is not reading in the css class correctly in my c# code. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you just create a specific image with the text already on it?

Comment: Mainly because I don't have photoshop

Comment: What should your c# code do? what is its output? What `class='img-valign'` mean?  which html tag does it apply to?

Comment: There are plenty of other options that are free, try inkscape

Answer (score 0):

The class should be an attribute in the element:

```
myBuilder.AppendLine("<img src='../myImages/checkmark.png' class='img-valign' /> Successful Upload!");
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me, I get the same result, which is nothing

Comment: @codeFinatic: If you get nothing, then that C# code is probably not executed at all, or the result from it isn't used in the page.

Comment: When I say nothing I mean that i get nothing on vertical alignment. The image and message show up, just not aligned correctly

Comment: @codeFinatic: When I try the code itself, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/aj9zcaa6/